Force parent process to be set to init(1) when process is orphaned
I have a process (X) that is spawned by another process (Y). Prior to the spawn, Y set itself as a subreaper (using prctrl PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER). Is there any way a fork from X can skip Y and have its ppid be 1 (init) when X terminates?
Ideally a Linux C api call, but I will take any other option

This makes no sense. A child obviously cannot change its parent's identity. The general convention is that the first process started by the kernel gets PID 1, and the system shuts down when that process exits.

@tripleee A child cannot set its ppid. It can manipulate things to cause the kernel to set its ppid. Daemons do this all the time by forking and exiting the parent to force the ppid to be the init process. I want to do this, but make sure I get the init process and not a subreaper along the way

I think the answer is "not easily, and not while playing by the rules".  The whole point of subreapers is to to allow sandboxing and security boundaries, so it seems the only use case for bypassing that mechanism is some nefarious intent.

AFAIK there's no way for a process to override the subreaper setting from its parent. That overrides the default use of PID 1 as the subreaper for all its descendants.
